# Orchard how to make homepage address also accessible by index

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Supposed my home page at the moment is: www.myorchard.com

How do I make it when user access www.myorchard.com/index also goes to home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want that. For good SEO, a resource should always correspond to one URL. What you want to do is redirect from one to the other, permanently. You can do that either using IIS's rewrite URL module, or through this Orchard module: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.RewriteRules

The former solution is to be preferred for less overhead, but if you think you're going to have to manage lots of rewrites often, the latter is more convenient.